# Solving Systems of Congruence using CRT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I'm trying to solve the following set of congruence equations:

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x \equiv 1(\bmod 7) \hfill \\
  x \equiv 6(\bmod 11) \hfill \\
  x \equiv 5(\bmod 13) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

First, we can see that the 1st equation implies $x = 1 + 7z,z \in \mathbb{Z}$, so I substitute it instead of $x$ in the 2nd equation, i.e.

$$1 + 7z = 6(\bmod 11)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 7z = 5 + 11t,t \in \mathbb{Z}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 6 + 11t$$

But, already at this stage, it is evident that if we pick a number $t\in\mathbb{Z}$, the equation $6+11t$ will not equal to $1$ modulo $7$, eg. $6+11=17\quad\implies\quad 17 \mod 7 =3$.

Why is this case? Is it important to try to reduce the equation to a single term, i.e. $z=\dots$?, vs. the way I've done?

Answer (score 1):

You left off the "$z=$" in "$\implies 6+11t$".  If you let $z=6+11t$ then $x=1+7z = 1+7(6+11t)$ and that will work just fine.